# How can I display 2d array as image (jpg, png) in Python?

Tags: python, image

I have

```
rows, cols = (5, 5)
arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
```

and want to get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5XYY.png)

It would be very convenient if the image had a dynamic resolution for each array.

Additionally, it is not clear what to do if I want a beautiful design - where to store and how to interact with the image template so that it can be dynamically changed and an array placed on it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITjzn.png)

Are there any ready-made libraries for my wishes? Or is this not usually done in python at all? Then how to automate it? It just feels like I'm reinventing the bike.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to show images by using matplotlib.

```py
rows, cols = (5, 5)
arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(arr)
plt.show()
```